# configure mysql with grafana

Tags: mysql, grafana

I want to work with grafana with MySQL as my backend.

I tried to do the following changes in defaults.ini

```
type = mysql
host = 127.0.0.1:3307
```

for the following line
    #mysql: go-sql-driver/mysql dsn config string, e.g. `user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/database_name`

I don't know what changed to do in it.

My $GOPATH is set correctly in .bashrc file

```
/Users/skhare/sk/go_new
```

For mysql, i also found this as follows

```
go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

I checked for the path

```
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

It exists and the contents are as follows:

BANL13bc92fb6:mysql skhare$ ls -lar

```
total 456
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   8708 Sep 21 14:00 utils_test.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users  19441 Sep 21 14:00 utils.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users    729 Sep 21 13:56 transaction.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   2243 Sep 21 14:00 statement.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   1814 Sep 21 14:00 rows.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users    600 Sep 21 13:56 result.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users  27119 Sep 21 14:00 packets.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   4160 Sep 21 14:00 infile.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users    989 Sep 21 13:56 errors_test.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   3459 Sep 21 14:00 errors.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users  38007 Sep 21 14:00 driver_test.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   3367 Sep 21 14:00 driver.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   2284 Sep 21 14:00 const.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   5551 Sep 21 14:00 connection.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   7969 Sep 21 14:00 collations.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   3173 Sep 21 13:56 buffer.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   4167 Sep 21 14:00 benchmark_test.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users    470 Sep 21 13:56 appengine.go
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users  13869 Sep 21 14:00 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users  16726 Sep 21 13:56 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   1607 Sep 21 13:56 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   3653 Sep 21 14:00 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users   1178 Sep 21 14:00 AUTHORS
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users    104 Sep 21 14:00 .travis.yml
-rw-r--r--   1 skhare  CORP\Domain Users     78 Sep 21 13:56 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x  13 skhare  CORP\Domain Users    442 Sep 22 10:21 .git
drwxrwxrwx   3 skhare  CORP\Domain Users    102 Sep 21 13:56 ..
drwxrwxrwx  28 skhare  CORP\Domain Users    952 Sep 21 14:00 .
BANL13bc92fb6:mysql skhare$ pwd
/Users/skhare/sk/go_new/src/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

But when i try to run the code

```
go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

It says message like

```
$GOPATH variable is not set.
```

I want to show metrics stored with mysql as my project uses mysql as backend.
Please help me configure mysql with grafana.

Comment: Export GOPATH as mentioned in https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/docs/sources/project/building_from_source.md

Comment: I did exactly as the link you wrote said, but still the issue remanins open